# R: Number of nodes in rastertoPolygons

Tags: r, polygons, r-raster

The raster package in R contains the function [`rasterToPolygons()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf#page.170). It allows you to set the number of nodes per polygon to 4, 8 or 16.
What is the restriction to those three values based on? Why is it not possible to choose any number in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum number of nodes to create a polygon from a raster cell is four.

A higher number can be useful when you need to transform the coordinate reference system (crs) of the polygons, because a straight line in one crs is likely to be curved in another. The function allows adding nodes in the middle of each side (8) or adding three nodes on each side (16).

The number of nodes would normally be a factor of 4 (at least for square cells), but there is no fundamental  reason to restrict it to 8 and 16 --- that was just a choice of the programmer, who did not consider a more flexible function when he developed it, or did not have the time to do that. You can of course do so yourself or write the maintainer of the raster package and request it.